# How to link to a label using specific text

Tags: cross-referencing

So I am writing a programming book and I have a code example in it that I have labeled `\label{ex11}`. How can I later in the document make a link to it using custom text?

For example, I am writing somewhere later in the book, "As I mentioned in `the first one-liner`, ...".

Here  I want the text "`the first one-liner`" to be linked to `\label{ex11}`. So that when I click that text, the document jumps to the label. Any ideas how to do that?

If this was HTML, I'd just do `<a href="ex11">the first one-liner</a>` (just to give you a better understanding about what I want to do).

Answer (score 37):

This can be done with [hyperref](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/), like this

```
\hyperref[ex11]{the first one-liner}
```

See the [LaTeX/Hyperlinks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks) wiki for more examples.

Answer (score 5):

`As I mentioned in the first one-liner, \ref{ex11}".`

With package `fancyref` you can use `\vref` instead for results like
`as seen in Example 12 on the following page` which is possible with `as seen in Example~\vref{ex11}`

With `hyperref` all references are converted into links. And with `\href[options]{URL}{text}` you can link it with a specific text.

Comment: an alternative is package `varioref`

Comment: Whatever suits you mate!