# Link to equation and change text?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, equations

I am interested in linking to an equation - but being able to change the text.

I had thought I could combine [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/how-to-link-an-equation-in-latex) and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17075/how-to-link-to-a-label-using-specific-text), but I cannot seem to get it to work.

I have attempted a variety of syntaxes similar to

```
\hyperref[eq:name]{my text describing the equation here}
```

but I cannot seem to get it to work.

---

This is the code I am currently using (well my equation is considerably more complicated but I have the same problem here)

```
\begin{align*} 
 y = x\label{testp}
\end{align*}
\hyperref[testp]{generalized form}
```

I get the following warning

```
LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `testp' on page 4 undefined on input line 108.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this it is easiest to use a `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink` combination since you technically don't have a "counter that you can reference" - this is provided by `\refstepcounter`, which marks a position that you can hyperlink to:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amsmath,hyperref}
% Taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17138/5764
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\labeltarget}[1]{\Hy@raisedlink{\hypertarget{#1}{}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  y = x \labeltarget{testp}
\end{align*}
\hyperlink{testp}{generalized form}
\end{document}
```

Since `\hypertarget` sets its target at the baseline, it has to be raised for any practical application. See [`\hypertarget` seems to aim a line too low](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17057/5764).

Comment: This took a weird sequence of compiling but eventually worked (you seemingly need to compile the \newcommand successfully before you can use the \labeltarget). Thanks much - LaTeX is sure neat :)